# DropdownlistFor is returning a null value, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I need some help, on my view i am returning a null value. What i want to get is the list of value when creating dropdownlistFor. The problem is how do i resolve such error? Below is my logic and need some help as to how please team.

```
    // Model
      // This is for course-list.
  

       // This is for course-list.
        public class eNtsaDashboardViewModel
        {
            public string CourseName { get; set; }
    
            public List<eNtsaDashboardViewModel> CourseLicence { get; set; }
    
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
    
        }
    
// Mutliple Model
  public class RegCoursesViewModel
    {
        public eNtsaCourses Courses { get; set; }
        public eNtsaDashboardViewModel Dashboard { get; set; }
        public List<eNtsaDashboardViewModel> lsteNtsaDashboard { get; set; }
        public RegCoursesViewModel MainModel { get; set; }

    }
    //  View
                         @using (Html.BeginForm("SuperAdmin", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                                            {
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                <label for="Content-Licence" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Content Licence</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Dashboard.CourseLicence, new SelectList(Model.lsteNtsaDashboard)) **// Return a null object.**
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            }
    public ActionResult SuperAdmin() { 
    
    var list = new List<string>() { "Private(Copyrighted)", "Public Domain", "Creative Commons Licences", "CC Attribution", "CC Attribution Share ALike", "CC Attribution Non-Commercial", 
                    "CC Attribution Non-Commercial Share Alike", "CC Attribution Non Directive", "CC Attribution Non-Commercial No Directives" };
                ViewBag.list = list;
    return View();
    }
```

Comment: You never return a model - `return View();` returns a null view. You've put your list of options into the ViewBag but then tried to read it from the model. Make sure you understand the difference between the model and the viewbag.

Comment: @Adyson what exactly am i missing from the given logic?

Comment: You've written `new SelectList(Model.lsteNtsaDashboard)`, but 1) `return View();` shows that you aren't returning any kind of model object, so `Model` will be null in your view. And 2) Even if you returned a model, `lsteNtsaDashboard` would still be null because you didn't populate it. In fact I'm not even sure such a property exists in your model class. And 3) you've created `list` and added it to the viewBag but you aren't using it for anything in the view. Where exactly are you expecting the data to come from, to populate your SelectList? Your code at the moment doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you do it like this

```
var list = new List<string>() { "Private(Copyrighted)", "Public Domain", "Creative Commons Licences", "CC Attribution", "CC Attribution Share ALike", "CC Attribution Non-Commercial", 
            "CC Attribution Non-Commercial Share Alike", "CC Attribution Non Directive", "CC Attribution Non-Commercial No Directives" };

List<SelectListItem> select_list = new List<SelectListItem>();

var query = from li in list
    select new SelectListItem()
    {
          Value = li.ToString(),
        Text = li.ToString(),
    };
 select_list = query.ToList();
 ViewBag.list = select_list;
```

then in your `view`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Dashboard.CourseLicence, ViewBag.list as List<SelectListItem>)
```

Comment: thanks mate, one question the query from li(table name)??

Comment: No, not a table name it's from the static list you created earlier `var list`.

Comment: Ok i hear you, i am getting this exception on ViewSide, why raised that question. System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Dashboard.CourseLicence'.'

Comment: can you update your question with the complete model that contain `Dashboard.CourseLicence`.

Comment: if i am getting that exception from the View. Where is it accessing ViewData has no key? trying to understand the error there. Must i have to change that model property? I did update my model, please have a look at it.

Comment: For this code to work your `CourseLicence` must be `string` , because at the end you want one selected value.

Comment: I did but still getting same error on View side. public string CourseLicence {get;set;}

Comment: The Model you are using on top of this view is `@model YOUR_PROJECT.RegCoursesViewModel` right ?

Comment: Last thing try `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Dashboard.CourseLicence, ViewBag.list as List<SelectListItem>)` .

Comment: what could i be missing? i am still getting that error.

Comment: I'm really confused , sorry I couldn't help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through the Viewbag concept little mnre.
Here you are assigning the list value to the Viewbag and not using that value in the view.
In your case, I have done some modifications to your code.
In your controller,

```
public ActionResult SuperAdmin() {
      ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

      List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>()
      {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Private(Copyrighted)", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Public Domain", Value = "2" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "CC Attribution Non Directive", Value = "3" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Creative Commons Licences", Value = "4" },

      };
      ViewBag.list = list;
      return View();
}
```

Then change your View's dropdown to accept the Viewbag.list value.
In your View,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SuperAdmin", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {
        <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Content-Licence" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Content Licence</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Dashboard.CourseLicence, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.list)
         </div>
        </div>
   }
```

This is not a preferred way of doing the dropdown list, I just modified your code to be working.